# How can I mantain my connection string alive among the classes

Tags: c#, connection-pooling

I want to use a connection pooling in my C# project. I understand that one I get the connection to the SQL server, while I'm using the same connection string, the cash pooling will work.
However I have doubts about: how is the best practice to pass the connection string through my different classes? Should I pass the connection string as a parameter to the methods that use it to connect? (for instance each time that I need to do a query)

Comment: Not a big deal if you read it from your configuration file every time you need it

Comment: If the same method is going to run the same query on the same database every time the method is called- you can store the connection there (preferably retrieving it from the config file). Personally- since I have multiple methods running different stored procedures/queries, I have written a class and method to return whichever connection string I choose (which are stored in my `app.config`), based on a parameter passed. That way, I don't have to retype my connection string throughout several different methods.

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET has built-in connection pooling, and you can't really build a better one.

When you create a connection using a connection string, the Framework checks the connection pool to see if a connection with that connection string is available. If one is, it pulls it from the pool and returns it to you; otherwise, it creates a new one and returns that to you.

Similarly, when you close (dispose of) a connection, it is not immediately destroyed. 
When you close a connection with a specific connection string, it is not immediately destroyed. Instead, it is released back into the connection pool.

Automatic connection pooling can be disabled, so that you could roll your own solution, but it's not advisable.

EDIT:

As pointed out, I didn't answer the question in my original answer.

In general, you don't pass connection strings around. Instead, they are stored in a configuration file (either `web.config` or `app.config`), in the connectionStrings section. When you need a connection string, you retrieve it within the method that requires it using `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`.

Comment: Not sure if you are answering the question here. _how is the best practice to pass the **connection string** through my different classes?_

Comment: @Steve You're completely right. I misread the question, and this answer in no way addresses his question. I will leave it here, however, as an example to others of how to completely miss the point.